# Number of number in range $(l, r)$ satisfying XOR constarint

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Here's a questions that's been bugging for some time now:

> Define the set $S_n = \{k \oplus (k + n)\mid k \in \Bbb Z, k ≥ 0\}$ (here, $\oplus$ is bitwise exclusive OR). To put it another way, $x$ is a member of $S_n$ if there exists a non-negative integer $k$ such that $k \oplus (k + n) = x$.
>
> How many members x of Sn satisfy the condition $l \leq x \leq r$?

How can I solve this question? This is actually an algorithms question, but I cant seem to think of an algorithmic solution, so maybe number theory is what's needed here, any help?